# How to override DefaultHTTPErrorHandler format message

Tags: go, jwt, go-echo, jwt-go

I'm using the Echo framework.

How can I change this format response to my own format 
its error from JWT Library https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go

```
{
  "message": "invalid or expired jwt"
}
```

i want to change something like this

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": false,
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "messages": null
  },
  "result": null
}
```

i cant find how to do it to override **DefaultHTTPErrorHandler**

this customHttpErrorHandler

```
    e := echo.New()
    e.HTTPErrorHandler = func(err error, c echo.Context) {
        var (
            code = http.StatusInternalServerError
            msg  interface{}
        )

        type (
            Map map[string]interface{}
        )

        if he, ok := err.(*echo.HTTPError); ok {
            code = he.Code
            msg = he.Message
            if he.Internal != nil {
                err = fmt.Errorf("%v, %v", err, he.Internal)
            }
        } else if e.Debug {
            msg = err.Error()
        } else {
            msg = http.StatusText(code)
        }

        if _, ok := msg.(string); ok {
            msg = Map{"sempak": msg}
        }

        // Send response
        if !c.Response().Committed {
            if c.Request().Method == http.MethodHead {
                err = c.NoContent(code)
            } else {
                err = c.JSON(code, msg)
            }
            if err != nil {
                e.Logger.Error(err)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to catch the error from the *JWT* library. [Here](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/06ea1031745cb8b3dab3f6a236daf2b0aa468b7e/example_test.go) you can find an example (`ExampleParse_errorChecking`) how to do this.

When you know the error you can return your custom response
or use *Custom HTTP Error Handler* 
see details [here](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/error-handling)

> Custom HTTP error handler can be set via e.HTTPErrorHandler

```
func customHTTPErrorHandler(err error, c echo.Context) {
    // ...
}

e.HTTPErrorHandler = customHTTPErrorHandler
```

Comment: thanks, please check updated question.
how to resolve `e.Debug`